# How to loop column entries in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to iterate through all the rows in a MYSQL table given the column name. I'm looking through the PHP docs and StackOverflow questions, but for some reason the `while` loop method didn't exactly work. Here's what I have so far:

```
include 'dbcon.php';

$dbcon = getConnection();
$currentUser= $_COOKIE['currentUser'];
$getIpQuery = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT $currentUser FROM ipList");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($getIpQuery, MYSQLI_NUM);
printf(count($row));
for($x=0;$x<count($row);$x++)
{
    printf("%s", $row[$x]);
}
```

This code returns only the first entry in the table which looks like this

```
--------------------
placeholder    user //(same as $currentUser)
NULL           value1
NULL           value2
```

Comment: Yes, I want to select one column because each user has their "values". Also, wouldn't that take a long time once the database grows?

Comment: post the db schema please

Comment: You're SQL injecting yourself because you don't use prepared statements / bind variables. Imagine if I changed my `currentUser` cookie to `* FROM users WHERE username = 'admin' --`. Suddenly I'd get to see all of 'admin''s columns in the `users` table. This is **very insecure**.

Comment: As mentioned, using prepared statements and binding variables are much safer. A bit more work, but well worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks, but what are prepared statements? Also, I'm just prototyping. I'm planning to rewrite the whole thing on Google Cloud with Python :)

Comment: Here's the "usual" message we give to people: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @Carpetfizz => http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Thank you for the info. I've actually been using `mysqli` haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function `mysqli_fetch_array` returns only 1 row per call.
you need to iterate while the function returns values:

```
$result = mysqli_query($__CONNECTION__, $getIpQuery) 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    for($x=0;$x<count($row);$x++)
    {
        printf("%s", $row[$x]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I will mark as correct as soon as I can.

Comment: `currentUser = * FROM users --`.